# Remove Musty Smell from Silk Tie

Tags: cleaning, clothing, smell

I have inherited a large collection of silk ties. Unfortunately, they have developed a musty smell, I think from having been kept in a damp room.

I don't want to go to the expense of taking the ties to the dry cleaners, and I've heard that using water will ruin the silk and may damage the lining. Is there another way to eliminate the smell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a sunny dry day hang them outside

Comment: Yup, this is about the only thing that will actually work. Dry cleaning won't, washing won't [whether the material is suitable for water or not]

Comment: I am concerned that sunlight will yellow the silk. The Silk Association of Great Britain recommends keeping silk out of direct sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

you could soak them in 1 cap of fabric softener (light colored) with 1 cup of room temp. water for a few minutes,not add water. i apply this method to my fiance's ties. they will not shrink you apply with ingredients at room temp.I use Suavitel. It comes in a yellow, blue, pink and purple. Get the yellow bottle. it is light in color. If it says dry clean only ,then put 1 tablespoon of fabric softener ans one tablespoon of water. and steam it into the tie.from a distance so it only gets damp from the steam, not soaked and wet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do the following hack:

- Place ties in a container
- Please do leave some space for placing some activated charcoal
- Activated charcoal can absorb bad smell
- 1 full day can remove musty smell.
- If this did not resolve the issue, spray some perfume inside the container and leave it for one more day.